# Soft body friction

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, soft-body, rigidbody

I want to create in blender a scene like this one, attached here.
I have a past in cinema 4d, there was very easy to create this.
I tried in blender in this way:
I create a soft body sphere and a plane with collision physics. I tried to modify the "Friction settings" but nothing happen. 
How works friction with collision and soft body in blender?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Soft_final]

You have basically 2 options that influence **Friction** in **Soft Body** simulation. Make it 3.

### Collision object:

Here only **Damping** will influence friction of the simulation. Less **Damping** = less friction.

**Friction** in these settings is only for **Cloth**.

[image: object]

### Soft Body object:

In Soft Body object settings **Friction** is self explanatory but it seems that **Mass** is also influencing how friction will behave.

[image: Object]

Comment: Thank you very much!  I really appreciate your effort